# returning result from binary search tree

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to determine if a value is found in the binary search tree.

If it's found, the value is printed. If not, a message is printed saying it wasn't found.

My problem is that even when the value is found, the message is printed saying that it wasn't found.

My result seems to reset even after returning True, and I am confused as to why this is happening... I think it's because I'm calling the function recursively, but I don't know how to fix this problem. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
def lookUpVal(bst,val,result):

if bst == None:#base case, if the tree is 0, return none
    return 

elif bst['data'] == val:
    print ("value found")
    result = True
    return result

lookUpVal(bst['left'],val,result)
lookUpVal(bst['right'],val,result)


def main(bst):
print ("Enter the value you want to find")
val = int(input())
result = 0
lookUpVal(bst,stud,result)
if result != True:
    print ("Value not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `result` variable, you probably think you are passing by reference, what is actually happening is close to pass-by-value.

Here is an example:

```
def voo(x):
    print('x:',id(x))
    x = True
    print('x:',id(x))

p = False
print('p:',id(p))
voo(p)
print('value of p:',p)
print('p:',id(p))
```

'id' returns a unique id for any object, including of course boolean ones.
Here's the output: (numbers will vary in your pc)

```
p: 1613433952
x: 1613433952
x: 1613433936
value of p: False
p: 1613433952
```

First note, `False` in output, `p`'s value has not changed. But to see why that's happening, closely examine the `id` values, specially how `x`'s id changed after assignment in function; which means python allocated a new object. And old one is still referenced by 'p', as evident in it's output, which has not changed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I tried printing out the IDs and I could see that my result has the same ID whether the value is found or not. How can I fix it so that it will actually return a different value? Should I not pass it in as a parameter?